# Cursor icon doesn't change inside constructor in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application that has the following constructor:

```
public BankApp()
{
    InitializeComponente();
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

    // some coding and setting up

    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
}
```

However, the cursor icon is not set to `WaitCursor`, for some reason, whereas if I do any other action, it is replaced properly.

I need this because in I want to prevent the user to take any action until all routines inside the constructor are called and finished.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In the constructor, the form probably isn't shown yet.

Comment: Also, setting the cursor doesn't prevent the user from doing anything.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError true. I guess they just tend to not do anything because they see that loading symbol.

Comment: Try inserting the code inside the `Form_Loaded` event method

Comment: It could also be the change happens too fast, you couldn't notice it, try deleting the 
`Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;` line and see whether you can see the mouse cursor change

Comment: While code is running on the UI thread, the form won't respond anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `Cursor` is a property of the form. The selected cursor displays when the mouse is moving over this form. But since the form is not yet visible when the constructor runs, the wait cursor cannot display.

Consider moving long running stuff to a `Shown` event handler:

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    try {
        Thread.Sleep(2000); // Do long running stuff here
    } finally {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    }
}
```

Instead, you could also set the wait cursor in the form which is opening this new form.

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
try {
    var frm = new BankApp(); // Constructor is running here.
    frm.Show();
} finally {
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
}
```

If your form is not the main form, you can use the following code to set the wait cursor for all open forms. This should also work in the constructor:

```
Application.UseWaitCursor = true;
try {
    Thread.Sleep(2000); // Do long running stuff here
} finally {
    Application.UseWaitCursor = false;
}
```

The try-finally ensures that the default cursor is also reset, if something should go wrong.

Comment: Very well-explained. Thanks!